# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'browse'

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I am having trouble in getting data from res.company
Can someone tell me why this code gives me an error ?

```
    def refresh_calculation(self,cr,uid,ids, context=None): 
        company_pool = self.pool.get('res.company')
        company_id = self.pool.get('res.company')._company_default_get(cr, uid, 'res.company', context=context)
        loan = company_pool.browse(cr, uid, company_id)

        administration_fee = loan.administration_fee.id
        interest_rate = percentage_to_float(loan.interest_rate.id)
        trade_mark = percentage_to_float(loan.trade_mark.id)

        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'monthly_installment': administration_fee})
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.pool.get` is returning None for "res.company". If that's a dict, it doesn't have that key.

Comment: Could you tell me what to do ? I am new to openerp. Thanks,

Comment: That is the right answer in python scope. In openerp scope something is very wrong with your openerp installation when the pool can't get res.company from the pool, because that's an openerp base orm class.

Answer (score 2):

`company_pool` returns the value `None`. Because `self.pool` does not have the key value 'res.company'. When `company_pool.browse(...)` is used -> `None.browse(...)` is called and this throws an error because `NoneType` does not have a browse attribute. Populate the value map `pool` before the `refresh_calculation(...)` is called or perform a None check before accessing this function -> `if company_pool is not None:`

Comment: what will i do to have the key value 'res.company' ?

Comment: Perform a None check before accessing the function or call self.pool.__setitem__( 'res.company','<value>') before calling the function

Comment: That is not what stackoverflow is for. Besides that, I don't know what your program is about

Answer (score 1):

Your `company_pool` parameter has `None` stored in it for some reason. To prevent this error, a simple if statement would suffice.

```
if company_pool is not None:
    # doSomething
else
    print "You did not enter the parameter res.company"
```

Comment: Now try using it. Replace dosomething with your code starting from company_id